# How to get the distinct record name and its each record count to bind to gridview in C# using Linq from SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

How to get the distinct record name and its each record count to bind to gridview in C# using Linq from SQL Server?

I tried in below format:

```
var txtquery = from ep in ebsuite.enquiryprocess
               where(UserID == ep.UserID)
               select new 
                        {
                            CourseName = ep.CourseName.Distinct(),
                            RecordCount = ep.Count()
                        }.SingleOrDefault();

return txtquery;
```

Comment: `where ep.UserID == UserID && (ep.Start.Date >= startDate.Date && ep.Start.Date <= endDate)`

Comment: For count `txtquery.Count();`

Comment: `var txtquery = (from ep in ebsuite.enquiryprocess
            where ep.UserID == UserID && (ep.Start.Date >= startDate.Date && ep.Start.Date <= endDate)
            select new 
            {
                CourseName = ep.CourseName

            }).Distinct();
    
    var count = txtquery.Count();

    return txtquery;`

Comment: Does it worked?

Comment: *how to get the individual record count* the count gives you individual count and you can use a list which contains your query record and count and return it. in that case you have to handle it.

Comment: It's not actually you are looking for?

Comment: it is working but need each record count too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to your query to:

```
var txtquery = (from ep in ebsuite.enquiryprocess
        where ep.UserID == UserID && (ep.Start.Date >= startDate.Date && ep.Start.Date <= endDate)
        select new 
        {
            CourseName = ep.CourseName

        }).Distinct();

var count = txtquery.Count();

return txtquery;
```